# How can I use delay() with show() and hide() in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, delay, show

How can I use `delay()` with `show()` and `hide()` in Jquery ?

Answer (score 180, accepted):

Pass a *duration* to `show()` and `hide()`:

> When a duration is provided, `.show()` becomes an animation method.

E.g. `element.delay(1000).show(0)`

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/MMsML/)

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way is to make a "fake show" by using jquery.

```
element.delay(1000).fadeIn(0); // This will work
```

Comment: How is this a "fake" show? And why not just use `.show(0)`?

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you try the **fadeIn()** instead of using a show() with delay().
I think what you are trying to do can be done with this.
Here is the jQuery code for fadeIn and FadeOut() which also has inbuilt method for delaying the process.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('element').click(function(){
      //effects take place in 3000ms
      $('element_to_hide').fadeOut(3000);
      $('element_to_show').fadeIn(3000);
   });
}
```

Comment: fadeIn and showing something with a delay are two completely different things

Answer (score 1):

from jquery api

Added to jQuery in version 1.4, the `.delay()` method allows us to delay the execution of functions that follow it in the queue. It can be used with the standard effects queue or with a custom queue. Only subsequent events in a queue are delayed; for example this will not delay the no-arguments forms of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue.

http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0):

This info needs updating.

I was looking at this today because I needed to delay the showing of a div. I'm using jQuery 3.4.1 and have tested this.

```
 $("#mydiv").delay(5000).show(200); // a 5 second delay before the 200 microseconds animation effect from hidden to visible is triggered.
```

Comment: This answer is 100% correct and has been tested. It should not be voted down.

Comment: I guess it's because people stop reading and try a `$("#mydiv").delay(5000).show();` which DOES NOT work. You have to set any parameter for show to get it to work (e.g. `$("#mydiv").delay(5000).show(0);`), see accepted solution below.