# How can i use jQuery's .delay() method with .hide() or show()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I use delay() with show() and hide() in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508644/how-can-i-use-delay-with-show-and-hide-in-jquery)

How to use jQuery's .delay() method with .hide() or show()?

the following doesn'tworks:

```
$("#element").val("").delay(250).hide();
```

but this does:

```
$("#element").val("").delay(250).slideUp("slow");
```

Any work-arounds?

Comment: Oops seems i pasted the wrong code at the first time, just updated it and added an online demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what about using `fadeOUt('slow')` for hidding ?