# how to use show() and hide() with delay()?

Tags: jquery

i want to show an image for a period of time after clicking a button and, while the image is showing, i want to hide the button.
here is my code

```
function showimage(button, image, imagesrc){
    $(button).click(function(){
        if ($('img#'+image).length === 0) {
            $('<img id=' + image + ' src=' + imagesrc + ' style={display: none;}>').insertBefore(button);
        }

        $(button).hide();

        $('img#'+image).slideDown(500).delay(2000).slideUp(500);

        $(button).show();
    });
};
```

but `show()` and `hide()` won't follow the delay, what should i do?

Comment: `.hide(0) or .show(0)` to put it in queue

Comment: why wrap the click event inside a function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I use delay() with show() and hide() in Jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508644/how-can-i-use-delay-with-show-and-hide-in-jquery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use delay before show.

```
    $(button).delay(500).show(0);

    $(button).delay(500).hide(0);
```