# Show/Hide cascading menu while hovering element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to show/hide a cascading menu when the user move the mouse on a certain element. This is quite easy to achieve with jquery, using the hover function:

N.B: The timer is used only to hide the menu after 200ms, and is not important.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var timer;
    $('.element,.cascading_menu').hover(function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $('.cascading_menu').show();
    }, function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function(){$('.cascading_menu').hide();},200);
    });
});
```

I have to repeat this code for every menu I want to hide.
But since I have a lot of menus, I would like to reduce the code length.

My idea was to use an array of "*id of element hovering:id menu to show/hide*".

Do you think it is possible to write a jQuery function that, given this array of elements, provide to show each menu, without having to write that code a dozen of times?

Comment: could you provide a fiddle?

Comment: You can remove the `setTimeout` and instead use `.delay(200)` (I know you said that part isn't important, but it saves a few lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks very much for your answers. At the end I wrote this code, that works quite well.
The problem was that the elements to show weren'e sons of the element hovered, so I creted two array, one with the element hovering, and the other with the element to show, and combined all with the **$.each** function. Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var timer;
        var h1=["prof","notif_cont","explo"];
        var h2=[".profile",".notification",".explore"];
        $('.hover').hover(
            function(){
                var hoverrato=$(this).children(':first');
                $.each(h1, function(indice,checker){
                    if($(hoverrato).hasClass(checker)){
                        var index_hov=indice;
                        ul_show=h2[index_hov];
                        clearTimeout(timer);
                        $(ul_show).show(65);
                    }
                });

            },
            function(){
                timer = setTimeout(function(){$(ul_show).hide(65);},200);
            });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this` so you can use the same code for all the elements, but it all depends on you html code formatting.

**[Here is an example.](http://jsfiddle.net/promatik/94mDu/1/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.element').hover(function(){
        $(this).find(".cascading_menu").stop().slideDown();
    }, function(){
        $(this).find(".cascading_menu").delay(200).slideUp();
    });
});
```

***Note:*** You can also use `delay(ms)` instead of a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I would set it up like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/pJZ86/), which will work for menus with depth, provided each `<li class="hoverli">` with a submenu has a submenu that is an unordered list (`<ul class="file_menu">`). It is important to [pass a duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508644/how-can-i-use-delay-with-show-and-hide-in-jquery) (i.e., zero) to `.hide()` or `.delay()` [will not work](https://api.jquery.com/delay/), as it doesn't use the effects queue without a set duration.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="button">
    <ul class="hover">
        <li class="hoverli">Hover over me!
            <ul class="file_menu">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>                
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="hoverli">or me!
            <ul class="file_menu">
                <li class="hoverli">submenu!
                    <ul class="file_menu">
                        <li>A</li>
                        <li>B</li>
                        <li>C</li>
                        <li>D</li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>                
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(".hoverli").hover(function(){
    $(this).find("ul").show();
}, function(){
    $(this).find("ul").delay(200).hide(0);
});
```

**CSS:**

```
ul, li {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    list-style:none;
}
.menu_class {
    border:1px solid #1c1c1c;
}
.file_menu {
    display:none;
    width:300px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
}
.file_menu li {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good example of a "Windows 7" style cascading menu [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a8vQv/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.hasDropdown').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul:first').show();
    },function(){
        $(this).find('ul').hide();
    })

});
```

it will cascade infinitely deep :-) in theory