# Jquery delay() is not working as expected

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am submitting my form with jQuery using an AJAX request. After successfully submitting the form I want to show a success message for 3 seconds and then I want to hide this success message. To do that I am using following code using the jQuery `delay()` method.

But somehow this `delay()` method is not working as I expect it to. It's immediately showing the message and then hiding the message.

I want to show the message for 3 second then it should be hidden. Can you please tell me why it's not working?

```
function upload_project_doc(element, event) {
    e = $(element);
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#up_project_doc_img').show();
    var formData = new FormData(e.parents('form')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        url: 'up_project_doc.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function () {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#project_up_result").html(data);
            $('#project_up_result').show();
            $('#project_up_result').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');
            $('#up_project_doc_img').hide();
            getProjectForm(<? php echo $p_id; ?>);
        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
}
```

My form is little bit big but it's look like that :

```
<td align="left" width="160">
  <button class="search_submit" onclick="upload_project_doc(this,event);">
    <b>Upload</b>
  </button>
</td>
```

Comment: Try `$('#project_up_result').show().delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');`

Comment: @artm I am trying it.

Comment: @atm it's not working as expected.

Comment: @artm this is exactly same behaviour as OP's code

Comment: Provide relevant HTML markup in question itself. BTW, are you submiting the FORM? If the FORM is submited, the page is refreshed/redirected (depending action attribute)

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508644/how-can-i-use-delay-with-show-and-hide-in-jquery `.show(0)`

Comment: @artm issue isn't in this part of code  `$('#project_up_result').show();
            $('#project_up_result').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow');`

Comment: @Wolff I updated my question, Please check it.

Comment: @Wolff yes I am submitting the FORM with jquery /. ajax method.

Comment: You are delaying the fade out and immediately after that hiding it. Remove this line of code $('#up_project_doc_img').hide();
 and it should work for you.

Comment: @KingSize I am trying it.

Comment: @KingSize not working because It's different id to hide my animated image.

Comment: @KingSize It could be it if element is ancestor of other one but OP just posted minimum as HTML markup, so **we** have now to ask again if he can post relevant HTML markup... Or better, a jsFiddle replicating issue. BTW, what is `getProjectForm()`???

Comment: Do these 2 ids have anykind of parent-child relationship?

Comment: Alternatively, you may also try using setTimeout

Comment: @KingSize no there is no parent-child relationship.

Comment: Some markup of how your form looks like on success would help.

Comment: post the html for the id's in question

Comment: @KingSize if it's possible can you see my full code via TV or Skype ?