# JQuery showing and hiding p elements one after the other

Tags: jquery, html, loops, hide, show

I am trying to loop through multiple p elements using JQuery to show and hide them but I just can't get it to work. I've also tried a for loop. The current shows and hides all the p elements and I would like to show and hide them one after the other. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<p hidden="" class="tweet-1">"Lorem Ipsum"</p>
<p hidden="" class="tweet-2">"Lorem Ipsum"</p>
<p hidden="" class="tweet-3">"Lorem Ipsum"</p>
```

etc

**JQuery**

```
var i=0
    $("p").each(function() {

    $(".tweet-" + i).show().hide();
    i+=1

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$("[class^=tweet-]").each(function(index){   
  $(this).delay(500*index).fadeIn();  
});
```

but i need to change the "hidden" attribute in paragraph with css display none.

```
<p class="tweet-1" style="display:none">"Lorem Ipsum 1"</p>
<p class="tweet-2" style="display:none">"Lorem Ipsum 2"</p>
<p class="tweet-3" style="display:none">"Lorem Ipsum 3"</p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I might not have been clear enough: I want to fade in tweet-1, fadeout tweet-1 and then fade-in tweet-2, fadeout tweet 2 etc. This method is an improvement to my attempt but it still shows all the p elements simultaneously.

Comment: Figured it out:  if you want the specific effect that I was looking for (fading in/out elements one by one) you need to set index equal to the sum of your fadeIn().fadeOut(). For example (1000*index).fadeIn(500).fadeOut(500);

Answer (score 1):

if you want the p elements to show only one at a time then the best way to achieve this functionality is to use jQuery promises. Also, you might consider using  i = 1 instead of  i = 0  since you do not have a class "tweet-0".

```
var i=1;
var arrayOfPromises = [];

$("p").each(function() {

    if (i == 1)
    {
        $(".tweet-" + i).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $.when(arrayOfPromises[i-1]).done(function() {
            $(".tweet-" + i).show();
        });
    }

    arrayOfPromises.push($(".tweet-" + i).hide());
    i+=1;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure to understand.

But fix your js :

```
var i=0;
$("p").each(function() {
$(".tweet-" + i).show(1000).hide(2000);
i+=1;
});
```

And I think it will be good that you add a delay(), like : [How can I use delay() with show() and hide() in Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508644/how-can-i-use-delay-with-show-and-hide-in-jquery)